# error to ionic in ubuntu 17.10.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ionic-framework, installation

friends I have the following problem to install ionic

I already have correctly installed nodejs and npm

then install ionic with sudo npm install -g ionic

when I try to consult the installed version, I find the following error:

```
ionic –v
```

[ERROR] Unable to find command: –v

```
    You may need to be in an Ionic project directory.
```

the strange thing is that I was able to install monaca and that works well, although monaca also uses ionic.

What I can do?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using a dash character (–) instead of the hyphen (-).

When I run your command (`ionic –v`) on Ubuntu 16.04 I get that same error, but then if I use the hyphen (`ionic -v`) I get the version out.